# How to display image on web page based on selected value from select field without reloading page

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to figure out how to display an image on the webform page when a certain `option` is selected from the `select` field.  And then getting the image to change when a different `option` is selected.  The url image link is stored in the Sqlite3 database with the respective `select` field options.  I am having trouble putting this all together and was wondering if someone may be able to help.  Here is some code that may make things easier to understand.

The `select` field I am focusing on is the `Host` field and the `extra` part of the `Host` class is where the URL image link is stored.

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
host = SelectField('Host Solution Required', choices = [], validators= . 
[validators.InputRequired('Please select a Board')])

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
form = LoginForm()
form.device.choices = [(device.id, device.name) for device in 
Device.query.filter_by(cat=None).all()]
form.host.choices= [(host.id, host.name) for host in Host.query.all()]
#if form.validate_on_submit(): To use this I will have to figure out how 
to validate the choices for device
if request.method =='POST':
    device = Device.query.filter_by(id=form.device.data).first()
    host = Host.query.filter_by(id= form.host.data).first()
    #This code takes care of changing the format of the ordering link 
that is put into bugzilla.
    if host.name =='None' and form.cat.data == 'None':
        return '<h1> You did not order anything, please go back and fill 
out cat or host</h2>'
    elif host.name == 'None':
        return '<h1> ({} x {}) for {}</h1>'.format(form.number.data, 
device.name, form.team.data)
    elif form.cat.data == 'None':
        return '<h1> ({} x {}-{}) for {} . 
</h1>'.format(form.quantity.data, host.name, form.finish.data, 
form.team.data)
    else:
        return '<h1> ({} x {}-{}) AND ({} x {}) for {} . 
</h1>'.format(form.quantity.data, host.name, form.finish.data,
            form.number.data, device.name, form.team.data)
return render_template('form.html', form=form, street = host.extra)

class Host(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    customer = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    engineering = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    extra = db.Column(db.String(400))

@app.route('/host/<name>')
def host(name):
hosts = Host.query.filter_by(name = name).all()
hostArray = []

for host in hosts:
    hostObj = {}
    hostObj['id'] = host.id
    hostObj['name'] = host.name
    hostObj['extra'] = host.extra
    hostArray.append(hostObj)

return jsonify({'hosts':hostArray})
```

```html
<br>
  {{form.host.label}}
  {{form.host}}
  <img src={{street}} alt = 'pic' align = 'right' width = '200' height = 
'200' />
<script>
var host_select = document.getElementById("host");
host_select.onchange = function() {
  name = host_select.extra;
  fetch('/host/' + name).then(function(response)){
    response.json().then(function(data)){
        for(host of data.hosts){
            document.getElementById("tweet").src= host.extra;
        }

    })
  });
}*/
</script>
```

The snippet above does not work, but it is where the image is being shown in the HTML.
Please let me know if I can clarify anything further.

Comment: _image to change when a different option is selected_ do you mean _at the moment_ it's selected on webpage or when it's selected, submitted and _then_ changes? P.S. At the moment, I can't see even a line of code related to an output of an image, there is no way for us to see what and where went wrong and how it can be fixed.

Comment: At the moment a different option is selected.  I've added to example code where the image is being shown in the HTML file.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Never mind I have figured it out.